# How can Android Services receive buttons and joystick motion events?

Tags: android, input, android-service

I'd like to be able to detect the use of a controller (buttons and joysticks) from outside of an app I'm working on. Apps like **[this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.poke64738.usbjoy&hl=en)** are able to intercept joystick events, so I know that it is possible.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a way to detect any use of a controller from outside of an app. what you said maybe is sending broadcast when click it or some action. then you can register a BroadcastReceiver to detect it.